# Batmanjs image upload

Tags: data-binding, carrierwave, batman.js

I'm using BatmanJs and Rails. I used carrierwave for uploading pictures and all worked fine. But, I am unable to show the image. The model has the attr photo.url which works fine. But I don't know how to bind a image tag.

I tried the following, with no result:

```
<img data-src="post.photo.url" />
<img data-bind="post.photo.url" />
```

But if I use

```
<span data-src="post.photo.url"></span>
```

it shows the url perfectly.

Kindly suggest how do i get it to work for img tag.

Comment: I've found the solution in a sample app... "data-bind-src"... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very close! try `data-bind-src`. Actually, you can use `data-bind-#{anything}` to bind html attributes to keypaths.